# Change out put of query result dynamically in sql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have table called test like this:

```
label  value
------------
Yes    01
No     02
```

When normally run query to select option 'yes';

```
Select label from table_name where value = '01';
```

for this query I'll get the answer 'Yes'. But I am trying to change the label to 'Yes, I have'...

it should be returned from query... Any idea about this???
Can we change the label while returning the data from query..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN label = 'Yes'
         THEN 'Yes, I have...'
         ELSE label END AS label,
    value
FROM table_name
WHERE value = '01'
```

This query will replace a `'Yes'` value from the `label` column with `'Yes, I have...'`, but the value will remain the same otherwise.